# Activate Sharepoint Feature when Solution is deployed

Tags: sharepoint-2010, wsp

I want to automatically activate a feature (specifically the SharePoint Server Publishing feature) automatically when I deploy a new wsp solution. Is this possible.

Where and How do I do this inside the visual studio Sharepoint project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Luis Please check this solution how to activate feature programmatically

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/9812889d-954a-43ef-9377-6561e91f3bbf/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the properties on the feature within VS -- there are a couple of options there that will control how the features behave when the solution is deployed via VS ( only ).. these settings have no affect on the solution  once it is out of VS...

1. Activate On Default - Indicates whether the feature is activated
   during installation
2. Always force Install - Indicates whether the feature is installed by
       force, even though it is already installed.
3. Auto Activate in Central Admin - Indicates that the feature is
       activated for administrators in CA...